# ROBOCOPY command gives me error if owner is set to group instead of user

Tags: permissions, script, windows-server, robocopy

I want to copy folder structure with permissions using this command: `ROBOCOPY "source" "destination" /E /copy:DATSO /NP /MT`. It works only if `source` folder is owned by the user that is trying to run this command, I don't understand why it doesn't work when I create a group `FCSubrangovai` and set that group as owner of `source` folder. Even though my user is a member of that group, the script doesn't work and I get this error: `This security ID may not be assigned as the owner of this object.`

Script works when owner of `source` is set to user `test`:
[image]

Script doesn't work when owner of `source` is set to group `FCSubrangovai`:
[image]

Example of that's happening:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Also, user that I use has Full control permissions on `6. SUBRANGOVAI`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed so solve this problem by removing `O` option from robocopy command `ROBOCOPY "source" "destination" /E /copy:DATSO /NP /M`. So it's `ROBOCOPY "source" "destination" /E /copy:DATS /NP /MT`. Now any user with "Change permissions" permission can use my script that I have written.